# How get Lot/Serial number in Netsuite SuiteScript 2.0 for Inventory Adjustment Transaction?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I'm trying to get the serial numbers from a inventory adjustment in a user event script. The following code works very well for me when the amount to adjust is positive, but not when it is negative.

```
var invDet = transaction.getSublistSubrecord({sublistId:'inventory',
                                              fieldId:'inventorydetail',
                                              line:x});

for(var y = 0; y = invDet.getLineCount('inventoryassignment'); y++) {

    var lotNumber = invDet.getSublistValue({sublistId:'inventoryassignment',
                                     fieldId:'receiptinventorynumber', 
                                     line:y}); 
    log.debug('lotNumber', lotNumber);                         
}
```

[When adjust quantity is negative, receiptinvetorynumber is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8BvG.png)

I have tried using field id equal to 'issueinventorynumber' or 'binnunber' but the returned value is empty.

I found the following comment in [a NetsuiteHub forum](https://netsuitehub.com/forums/topic/accessing-inventoryassignment-detail-on-item-in-fulfillment/)...

> In 2.0 the getValue call returns the internal ID of the serial/lot number and the getText equivalent does not work. Depending on the exact logic you need to execute for the obtained numbers you might need to call a subsequent saved search to obtain the actual serial/lot numbers and not internal IDs (an 'inventorynumber' search will do the trick).

I tried this...

```
      try{
         var internalId = invdet.getSublistValue({sublistId:'inventoryassignment',fieldId:'internalid', line:y});
         search.create({type:'inventorynumber', filters:[
                           ['internalid', 'is', internalId]
                         ], columns:['inventorynumber']}).run().each(function (result) {
                          binText = result.getValue('inventorynumber');                  
                          log.debug('binText', binText);
                     });
       } catch(e) {
           log.debug('Error', e.message);
           throw e.message;
       }
```

I am too inexperienced to make this work. I appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is that this area of the NetSuite API is not well documented.  However, I pushed through it through trial and error and search hours.

```
var invDet = transaction.getSublistSubrecord({sublistId:'inventory',
                                              fieldId:'inventorydetail',
                                              line:x});

for(var y = 0; y = invDet.getLineCount('inventoryassignment'); y++) {

     var Qty = invdet.getSublistValue({sublistId:'inventoryassignment',
                                       fieldId:'quantity', 
                                       line:y});
     var lotNumber = '';

     if(Qty < 0)
     {
          var ivnNumId = nvdet.getSublistValue({sublistId:'inventoryassignment',
                                                fieldId:'issueinventorynumber',
                                                line:y});
          if(ivnNumId !== '')
          {
             var invNum = record.load({type: 'inventorynumber',id:ivnNumId});
             lotNumber = invNum.getValue({fieldId: 'inventorynumber'});
          }
     }
     else
     {
          lotNumber = invdet.getSublistValue({sublistId:'inventoryassignment',                                                                                
                                              fieldId:'receiptinventorynumber',
                                              line:y});
     }
 
     log.debug('lotNumber', lotNumber);                         
}
```

[This information was very helpful in ss1.0](http://www.netsuiterp.com/2019/05/get-serial-numbers-associated-with-item.html)
I hope it is useful to someone